# BrowserStack - Local Connection with pac file

Tags: browserstack

Did any one tried running tests on Browserstack using a local connection with a pac file.

BrowserStackLocal.exe --key XXXXX --pac-file proxy.pac

I've bee trying this for a while and the pac proxy configuration file is not getting to browserstack.

Comment: Can you share the error? Did you try using proxy options for the binary instead of pac?

Comment: No proxy won't do it because not all traffic should go through the proxy,only particular adresses. Tht=at's why we need a pac file.
No, there is no error, the browserstacklocal starts on the test runs sucessfuly but the browser opens in browserstack without the proxy settings, it's like the pac file was not taken into consideration by browserstack

Comment: Has the same thing. Can't make it work with pac file. The doc is not good at all. :(